# Having problems with TOD object detection

Tags: ros, object-detection, ros-groovy, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!
I have been cooking in the object recognition kitchen for a bit and so far I succeeded at creating my own models, uploading and training them using TOD.

Unfortunately I can't get the detection to work - i.e. zero poses found. The output looks like this:

```
***Starting object: 0
5 keypoints in 6 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 0 inliers
***Starting object: 1
12 keypoints in 51 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 0 inliers
***Starting object: 2
2 keypoints in 4 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 0 inliers
***Starting object: 3
4 keypoints in 4 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 0 inliers
***Starting object: 4
2 keypoints in 2 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 0 inliers
***Starting object: 6
6 keypoints in 24 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 0 inliers
********************* found 0 poses
```

Comparing this with the output shown in the [tutorial](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/detection/detection.html#detection) I noticed that I get very few keypoints and matches and RANSAC returns 0 inliers.

Any guess what is going wrong here?

*Side note*: I'm using Groovy with a source install on Ubuntu Precise 64bit and my sensor is the ASUS Xtion Pro Live.

**Update:**
I can report a tiny success! I switched to the Kinect, activated the high res mode (SXGA for both depth and rgb), captured and trained the new object and I'm getting a `found 1 poses` now.

```
***Starting object: 0
5 keypoints in 5 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 0 inliers
***Starting object: 1
85 keypoints in 1103 matches
done filling
RANSAC done with 52 inliers
RANSAC done with 5 inliers
```

Unfortunately, I don't get any (valid) output on the rostopics - markers, poses, recognized_object array are all empty. Is this a bug?

So, my question now turns into this one:
Does TOD only work with high res models and input?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71833/having-problems-with-tod-object-detection/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-08-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7086/bk/) on 2013-10-04**:
I also was not able get any poses using vga @ 30 fps.
bit-pirate: When I used --res sxga and --fps 15 on the object_recognition_capture pkg 'capture' executable, the program locks up. I am using:
-a Kinect
-set the dynamic reconfiguration(through rqt) to sxga @15fps
-using groovy/64bitUbuntu 12.04

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-10-06**:
Hm, hard to say. I haven't been using TOD for a while now, since the reimplemented tabletop object detector is sufficient for my needs. However I did the tests described above with the exact same specs as you. Could you provide more details about where/how the program get's stuck?

**Comment by [bk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7086/bk/) on 2013-10-07**:
The program hangs at: "Setting sync off".
One possible difference is that my depth resolution seems to stay at vga@30fps. Using rqt and dynamic reconfigure, I change the depth resolution to sxga @ 15fps but when I exit out of rqt and enter it again the depth goes back to vga@30fps.

**Comment by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on 2013-11-26**:
I am also getting a similar output. I am using kinect sensor, groovy, 64 bit. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related update, ORK using TOD and tabletop kind of works, I wrote a post with all the steps I followed to get some detections with them:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/object-recognition-kitchen/ijpfJdG9q8E/FPG4HtRBr4AJ

Using ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro, last ORK from sources, 32b and 64b tested.

---

Originally posted by [awesomebytes](https://answers.ros.org/users/4672/awesomebytes/) with karma: 66 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0